# HistoryApi.readDailyTotal() does not work on Wear device

Tags: android

I'm developing watch face for Android Wear. I want to show on the face the steps recorded only by the wear device. According to Google Documentation this is possible with [HistoryApi.readDailyTotal()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryApi#readDailyTotal(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType))

According to the documentation:

> The system does not require authorization to access the TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA data type from the HistoryApi.readDailyTotal() method. This can be useful if you require step data for use in areas where you are unable to show the permissions panel (for example, Android Wear watch faces and activities or widget activities). For more information on how to use this data in a watch face, see Showing Information in Watch Faces.

Unfortunately this does not work for me - GoogleApiClient always returns **Connection failed: 5** - This means:**The client attempted to connect to the service with an invalid account name specified.**

This is my client:

```
mFitnessApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MyWatchFace.this)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(Fitness.SCOPE_ACTIVITY_READ)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

Any idea how to tackle this problem? I'm facing hard time with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar issues getting the total on the wearable (local only), and this worked for me: do not add any scopes, and be sure to call useDefaultAccount. Hope this helps! 
Ex:

```
mFitnessApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MyWatchFace.this)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            // Do not add any scopes if using the client on the watch
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .useDefaultAccount() // Use the default account
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```