# GoogleApiClient will not connect when adding Fitness API

Tags: android, wear-os, google-fit

I have a Fitness GoogleApiClient in my Service that works perfectly... until I add the Fitness API.

```
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .useDefaultAccount()
            .build();
```

I have the exact same setup in my WatchService (for Android Wear) and it works perfectly without any issues at all... but as soon as I add it to the Service in the phone App... it will not connect at all.

If I take out these 2 lines - it connects right away.

```
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
```

Suggestions?

So it appears Fitness.HISTORY_API is requiring a Sign-In on the phone App - but not on the watch... Odd... I have tried with only Fitness.HISTORY_API and it still requires a Sign-In.

Comment: So does your `OnConnectionFailedListener` get called? Do you handle connection errors? The Google Fit API does require sign in (unlike the Wearable and LocationServices API).

Comment: Yes - I guess you are right... Why does this require a sign in on the phone but it doesn't on Wear?      onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{510f69a: android.os.BinderProxy@8781bcb}, message=null}

Comment: The only Google Fit API that doesn't require auth is the [HistoryApi.readDailyTotal() API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#read_daily_total_data) - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do... just read the daily total.

Comment: Then why do you have the `RECORDING_API`?

Comment: I used a sample app from Google and that's what it had - I have, however, tried it without the RECORDING_API and it still will not connect. (Same sign in error)

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33308447/5995040), hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

I had a `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` error at one point, too, and it wouldn't even ask for the sign in to my Google account, which sounds like what's happening to you. To request the sign in I used `ConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult` as follows below:

```
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
        Snackbar.make(/*...*/).show();
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting login...");

            ////////////////////////// HERE //////////////////////////////
            result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_LOGIN);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception however you like
        }
    }
})
```